# Cant install the debugger gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't install the debuggar gem.

I get this error and I have no ide why:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing debugger:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
Makefile creation failed
**************************************************************************
No source for ruby-1.9.3-p547 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
**************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby
    --with-ruby-dir
    --without-ruby-dir
    --with-ruby-include
    --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
    --with-ruby-lib
    --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/debugger-1.5.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/1.9.1/debugger-1.5.0/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Does [this](http://blog.houen.net/fix-gem-install-debugger/) help at all?

Comment: @PaulRichter it installs but i get the same error the I need to install debuggar 1.5.1

Comment: Sorry, you mean it installs, but the specific version (version 1.5.1) doesn't install correctly? Did you do the `gem install debugger-ruby_core_source` line first from that article?

Comment: Alternatively, I really like [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) with [pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger), if you can't get this to work.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I was having the same issue and this solved it for me:

```
gem update debugger-ruby_core_source
```

And then `bundle install` would work.

Comment: Works in Yosemite, with rbenv. Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm. "gem install debugger -v '1.6.6'" now works for me. :-)

Comment: What a pain, the Ruby? Why this command must even ever exist?! ... in case if the dependency already specified in Gemfile?!!

Answer (score 6):

Try it:

```
bundle update debugger
```

And keep in your gemfile:

```
gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: Worked for me also :)

Comment: Found myself in here when `bundle update rails` failed because of debugger. Tried to `bundle update debugger` as stated in answer, but it failed because rails was out of date and should be updated first… Solution? `bundle update rails debugger` :)